# Steganography. What is the decryption?

Tags: cipher, steganography

We were given an image that could be a barcode found hidden in it. However, I'm unable to read the barcode using an app after I re-created it and I'm unsure if I made an error or if it's an actual barcode.

[Original Image](http://puu.sh/gSv9s/378d5c7681.png)

[Red channel 6th bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbIxB.png)

[Re-created hidden image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRqIf.png)

[Flipped Re-created hidden image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khCuL.png)

To find the barcode hidden under the original image just change the contrast and levels of the image or use any of your different steganography techniques. I'm only guessing it's a barcode but [it may not be](http://gyazo.com/72ac4d5b430e24d37319f129ae2126d5) (this person had solved the puzzle).

So it possibly might not even be a barcode or I'm finding the wrong thing in the image.

All I can say is it was confirmed that the answer is **44 random characters**. It was confirmed by someone who has solved it.
The answer should be something like this. EGUKUEEQXAYLIKPPSKQPLIUFZXJUOGXQJZIUGOLLFOUL

**My Question:**

Is this a real barcode? If yes, how can we scan it/decrypt it? If not, what is it or is there something else I'm missing in the original image? Finally what is the decryption to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to thank Quark for the help of the answer. For some reason when the barcode wasn't scanning before. It finally worked using this website http://online-barcode-reader.inliteresearch.com/default.aspx.

Just take my flipped version and scan it there. You should get the answer. I'm not sure why it wasn't working before, but yeah. I guess it was just complete luck.

Comment: I was just editing my answer to tell you that, it comes out to MRKFJVAWKARPNOLSPOWRLKMERFVLIQXINYIJYXWPNYMD. By the way, that guy you linked on gyazo is such a troll if he actually knew it was a barcode.

Comment: @Quark Yeah haha. I've got another thing for everyone to solve coming soon. just waiting on the creator of this to release it.

Comment: @DoubleHelix is it possible for you to select your answer as the answer?  My OCD wants to be able to search for unanswered questions and this one keeps slowing me down ;)

Comment: @LeppyR64 that is the answer no worries.